# block some endpoints NOT to be send to application insights - nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-application-insights

I really like application insights and I use it in an nodeJs application.
This is what I have in my express.js

```
const appInsights = require('applicationinsights')
appInsights.setup()
    .setAutoDependencyCorrelation(true)
    .setAutoCollectRequests(true)
    .setAutoCollectPerformance(true)
    .setAutoCollectExceptions(true)
    .setAutoCollectDependencies(true)
    .setAutoCollectConsole(true)
    .setUseDiskRetryCaching(true)
    .start();
```

everything works fine. But I want that some specific requests NOT send to application insights

I run the application in an kubernetes cluster and have configured an Liveness and Readiness Probe (a lot of requests are done to this endpoints), but the requests to those endpoints are sent to application insights as well which is not what I want as it is blasting the application insights account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for the answer. I could make the change with the link you have provided.

implementation:

```
function removeStackTraces ( envelope, context ) {

  var data = envelope.data.baseData;  
  if (data.url && data.url.includes("health") )
  {
      return false;
  }
   return true;
}
 appInsights.defaultClient.addTelemetryProcessor(removeStackTraces);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use telemetry processor to filter out those requests you don't want sent.
Take a look at this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/#preprocess-data-with-telemetry-processors

generic doc (mostly .net)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor